# Python Pytest: test api with wrong body

Tags: python, pytest

The api I am using has some problems, so I want to correct it by using Pytest. I do not know if pytest can check the correct body data when I send a post request.

Code:

```
import requests
import json

def test_code_equals_200():

    url = "https://xxxxx.com/category"

    payload = json.dumps({
    "CategoryId": 1,  #required field, must be integer
    "CategoryType": "Apple"  #can only fill "Apple", "Banana" or "Cherry"
    }

    headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'x-api-key': 'ju876djg3jd8'
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

The code above will be passed when I use pytest to test it. However, if I use the wrong data like test1, test2 or test3, it still passed but I want the result to be failed

test1:(categoryID is not integer and CategoryType is wrong)

```
    payload = json.dumps({
    "CategoryId": "A",  
    "CategoryType": "Cake"  
    }
```

test2:(categoryID is missing)

```
    payload = json.dumps({  
    "CategoryType": "Apple"  
    }
```

test3:(categoryID is null)

```
    payload = json.dumps({  
    "CategoryId": "",
    "CategoryType": "Apple"  
    }
```

Is there anyway I can test it in my code?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html) decorator.

```py
import pytest
import requests


# here you define the test0, test1, test2, test3 dictionaries which are the payloads

@pytest.mark.parametrize(('payload', 'expected_status_code'), [(test0, 200), (test1, 400), (test2, 400), (test3, 400)])
def test_response_code(payload, expected_status_code):
    url = "https://xxxxx.com/category"

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-api-key': 'ju876djg3jd8'
    }

    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    assert response.status_code == expected_status_code
```

In this example, I used 400 Bad Request to validate the response with "wrong" request body, feel free to change them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! but how can I set the CategoryType value for only "Apple", "Banana" or "Cherry"? Using a list to do it?

Comment: You could save the `json.dumps` using requests json argument: `requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)`